# Microsoft Android Emulator - SQL Lite location

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am using Microsoft Android Emulator for testing my Native Android Applications developed using Java and SQLLite.

I am able to store data in the SQL Lite database and able to display the same on my APP. However, there are some columns which are not displayed in the APP's UI.

The only way to view those columns is to move the .DB file (SQL Lite database file) from my the SD card (of the Emulator) to one of the physical location and then view the same in SQLiteBrowser. I need to repeat this process everytime there is a new record in the table.

Is there a smart way to automate this process?

Appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you,
Prawin

Comment: you can temporary create your database in sd card too. Try that if it suites you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my script to pull the database:

https://gist.github.com/bigdestroyer/c66f50cf9b8f252f59be

First, it copies the database file from app databases directory (`/data/data/the.app.package/databases`) to SD card. And then it pulls the database file from SD card to local file system.

Comment: Thank you so much @bigdestroyer.